# Cant resolve url to Index Controller

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I've created a simple Zend Framework 1.12 test app via the zf.bat on my windows machine (xampp, php5.3): "zf create project testapp"

After that i've created an new controller called 'FoobarController' next to the 'IndexController'.
Now I can switch between these urls:

```
localhost/projects/testapp/public/

localhost/projects/testapp/public/index

localhost/projects/testapp/public/foobar
```

Now I have uploaded the whole testapp into the web server directory of my raspberry pi (192.168.1.100, Apache2, PHP5.3, ModRewite On, AllowOverride All).

This urls are working fine when I call the raspberry from the windows machine:

```
192.168.1.100/sites/testapp/public

192.168.1.100/sites/testapp/public/foobar
```

This one will display: "**The requested URL /sites/testapp/public/index was not found on this server**"

```
192.168.1.100/sites/testapp/public/index
```

Has someone an idea why the url to the "index" controller wont work properly on my raspberry? (I did nothing more than the explained steps)

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sites/testapp/public
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you transferred your data including folder structure? If yes and your folder on localhost looks like `/projects/testapp/public/` why should it be `/sites/testapp/public/` on your raspberry?

Have you tried calling our app with `192.168.1.100/projects/testapp/public/index`?

Comment: I have uploaded the whole "testapp" directory into "/var/www/html/sites" and "/var/www/html" is the docroot. I have disabled "multiviews" options in the httpd.conf. Dont know why but now the routing is working.